# Do (almost nothing) spark job hangs

Tags: apache-spark

Spark hangs when I run this:

```
  @Test
  def collectTest(): Unit = {

    val conf = new SparkConf()
      .setAppName(s"MyApp")
      .setMaster("spark://sp1:7077")

    val sparkContext = new SparkContext(conf)

    val data = Array(1,2)
    sparkContext.parallelize(data).collect().foreach(println)
  }
```

- the job shows up on the spark console
- and hangs indefinitely

[image]

Spark 1.6.1, Scala 2.11, connecting to standalone spark.

Comment: What are your spark submit arguments...what is your spark cluster capacity...it's probably not finding resources

Comment: Its run directly from a unit test (not as a batch job) and has no dependencies (the input is an Array and the only operation is collect. It looks like the VM network adapter was the issue. It would be better if the client established the necessary connections -- I suspect the server is trying to open a connection back to the client.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that this is what happens if you don't used VMWare in Bridged mode.  :-\

Turn on Bridged Mode people.